# Validate an array of custom fields in Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-validation

I have a Livewire form that displays one or many custom fields form a table. Some fields are required, some are optional. I generate the form fields like this:

```
@foreach ($event->fields as $index => $field)
    ...
    <input type="text" wire:model="fields.{{ $index }}.value" />
    @error('fields.{{ $index }}.value')
        <p>Error</p>
    @enderror
@endforeach
```

In my component, the rules are created like this:

```
foreach ($this->fields as $index => $field) {
    if($field->is_required) {
        $rules["fields.$index.value"] = 'required';
    }
}
```

The validation works, but the error messages for the fields are not displayed. How can I make the error messages work?
Thanks!